# Gradient Shading Under Density Plot in R (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to gradient shade under a density plot in R, using ggplot2. I keep getting the density plot, but no shading.

```
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)

getSymbols('XLE')
energy <- coredata(Delt(XLE$XLE.Adjusted, k = 1)["2018-03-08::"])
ggplot(energy, aes(energy)) +
    geom_density(aes(x = energy, fill = energy))+
    scale_fill_gradient2( energy ,
        low = "darkred", high = "navy", mid = "orange", midpoint = 0)
```

This yields a curve with no fill at all.

Here is a similar example with reproducible data:

```
test.data <- data.frame(exp(runif(1000,0,1)))

ggplot(test.data, aes(test.data))+
    geom_density(aes(fill = test.data)) +
    scale_fill_gradient(test.data, low = "navy", high = "red")
```

which yields

[image]

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ Can you reproduce this with a subset of data that you can share with us?

Comment: Okay, I have updated the original question to include an example with reproducible data.

Comment: I have no idea how your example produced the graph since the code has several errors, including not supplying `x` aesthetic to `geom_density`, and supplying data objects rather than colulmn names to `aes`. I also don't understand what the desired result is - how do you want this to be filled? the `fill` aesthetic is discrete for `geom_density`. In your original code, if you set `x` and `fill` to the same continuous variable `fill` would do nothing, and it's unclear what you would be expecting it to do.  please look at the examples: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density.html

Comment: Simplest solution would be: draw histogram under the density and color it according x-axis values

Comment: I'm trying to link the color of the fill under the curve with the value of the x-axis. Rather than one fill color, I would like the color to change from "navy" to "darkred".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I spent the weekend looking into this, and I finally came up with the answer for shading under a density plot relative to the x-axis in R.

Let's set some reproducible data:

```
input = runif(1000, 0, 1)
output = exp(input) + cos(input)
```

Then we need to add a faux-factor, "name", in a data frame:

```
name = rep("name", length(output))
data.df = data.frame(input, output, name)
data.df$name = as.factor(data.frame$name)
```

From here, we can use the ggplot2 and ggridges library:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)

ggplot( data.df, aes(x=output, y=name, fill=..x..))+
geom_density_ridges_gradient()+
scale_fill_gradient(low="red4", high="navy")+
ylab(" ")
```

Which yields:
[this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYgpf.jpg)